# How to check node positions in n-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Assume I have a n-ary tree with data in it, and data is not value-ordered.

What algorithm can be used to determine if node `n1`, is to the left or right of another node `n2`?

Comment: if data is not value ordered, any thing could happen!

Comment: trace the tree.  code each node with an n-ary number f(node) where each digit is 0,1,2,N-1... represents left to right.  most sig fig is closer to root.  n1 is left of n2 iff f(n1)<f(n2).